# loop the elements of an array into a variable for comparison

Tags: event-listener

start html ----------------------

```
div id="pageWrapper"> //page wrapper
<div id="page-image"><img src="./images/lightHouseB.png"></div>
<div id="man-image"><img src="./images/sailor.png"></div>
<section>
<header>There Are Things in the Dark, can you Find them? </header>
<!-- basic html title page --> 


<div id="textBox">
<a id="mousee" href="#">Hidden Ships</div></a>
</div>
</section>
```

html end point -----------------------------------

```
 window.onload = eventMonitor();

function eventMonitor(){
    document.getElementById('manimage').addEventListener('onmouseover', popMap(), false);
    document.getElementById('mousee').addEventListener('click', shipsSlider(), false);

    function popMap(url='shipsSlide.html',windowName, w, h) {
        var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
         var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
          return window.open(url=" ", "Ship Pictures", toolbar='no', directories="no", status='no');
    }
```

keep getting a null value - can not read property of eventlistener of null.

Comment: It means that, going by the code you've provided here, the `document.getElementById(...)` isn't finding a value and thus it is `null` and so you can't call the `addEventListener` function on a null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference the function to `window.onload`, and it will be called once the window loads.

See the difference here.

```js
window.onload = onload;


function onload(){

  console.log('DOM loaded');

}
```

And here I am referencing whatever `onload` will return, in this case a function.

```js
window.onload = onload(); // This will return the anonymous function of onload
// __________________|^^|

function onload(){

  return function(){ 
      console.log('DOM loaded');
  }

}
```

So what you want to do is to remove `()` so your code becomes:

```
window.onload = eventMonitor; // eventMonitor will be run once windows loads.
```